# RPi.GPIO module ImportError in python venv

Tags: python, import, module, gpio, python-venv

I've got a script which is running in a Python Virtual Environment. It contains some GPIO code. But for some reason the RPi module can't be imported, even with sudo. Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: what do you mean imported? installed maybe?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ No, it's definitely installed. I mean everytime I start it, the console tells me I've got an ImportError.

Comment: Do you have `rpi.gpio` installed in your virtualenv? If you do, can you confirm that your virtualenv is activated when you run your script

Comment: @OluwafemiSule How can I install it in the venv?

Comment: after activating your virtual environment, run `pip install rpi.gpio`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you! Now it works perfectly.